# "To be", "be" or neither

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I have always been confused about these three sentences:

> I want no more foreign language *to be* spoken in this class.
>
> I want no more foreign language *be* spoken in this class.  (Subjunctive)
>
> I want no more foreign language spoken in this class.

Are these sentences all fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last one is the most natural. The first is passable, but not natural, while the second is ungrammatical. The subjunctive would be something like "I insist/demand [that no more foreign language be spoken in this class]".

Comment: @BillJ what about "I want to hear no more foreign language spoken in this class."

Comment: That's OK, as would be "I don't want to hear any more foreign language spoken ...".

Comment: @BillJ is it a valid structure: "want something done" like, 'want him beaten up', 'want the work done'?

Comment: Yes, it's alright..

Answer (score 0):

All don't sound right.

As a native English speaker I would say it like this:
*I do not want any more foreign languages to be spoken in this class.*

This is also correct:
*I want no more foreign languages to be spoken in this class.*